# What does this option do HTTPD_MODULES_STRIP for HTTPD?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, cloud-foundry, pcf

Im using PHP buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack for CloudFoundry. The app bring up a dummy HTTPD webserver directing traffic to defined endpoint.

In .bp-config/options.json, i could see HTTPD_MODULES_STRIP.

What does this option accomplish?  Setting true or false, resulted in the same outcome. So curious, how is it being used?

If the extension has to be written to consume that option, how do i do that?

version of HTTPD 2.4.12

Answer (score 1):

When modules specified in your build manifest are zipped, setting `HTTPD_MODULES_STRIP` to `true` will cause the first element of the archived file's path to be stripped before placing it in the destination directory.

Example when `HTTPD_MODULES_STRIP = true`: When extracting file `archive.txt` into destination directory `intoDir`, directory "some" is removed from the resulting pathname.

> some/file/in/archive.txt -> intoDir/file/in/archive.txt

See `./lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py` line 312 and `./lib/build_pack_utils/zips.py` for more info.

Comment: If you are installing a package in your PHP buildpack extension, like here -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/lib/httpd/extension.py#L44-L45, the underlying code that installs the package will look for `<package-name>_STRIP` (here -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/lib/build_pack_utils/cloudfoundry.py#L211).  It does what's described above.  The `HTTPD_STRIP = true` config would set this for the `HTTPD` package.

Comment: The `HTTPD_MODULES_STRIP = true` is old and can technically be removed.  That was from a time long ago when the buildpack installed a core HTTPD + individual "modules" for different HTTPD extensions.  The idea was to install as small of a footprint as possible.  What this ended up doing was slowing down the buildpack as it takes more time to download and install multiple small files as opposed to one large file.  Plus the only thing this was saving is a bit of disk space, since HTTPD only loads the subset of the installed modules that are listed in it's config.